# How to Properly Bind Object(s) to a Treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, treeview

I have been teaching myself C# and have been wanting to write a WPF application that would use a treeview.  I am having a heck of a time figuring out how to get data binding to work with it though.

Could someone please tell me where I'm going wrong here?  At this point, I'm just trying to get something, anything to display in the tree.  The resources I've found that show how to use treeview have been quite confusing for me.

Thank you in advance for your time

**Edit:** Thank you for the responses.  Adding the ItemSource = {Cars} to the treeview has pulled in the Make of the two cars I've instantiated.  How do I go about making the car makes expandable to display the list of Features?  I will try to figure it out on my own, but any help is appreciated at this point because I've managed to get a bit frustrated with this one.

**Cars.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TreeViewTest
{
    public class Cars
    {
        public List<Car> CarCollection { get; set; }

    }

    public class Car
    {
        public String Make { get; set; }
        public String Model { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public List<String> Features { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace TreeViewTest
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private List<Car> _Cars;

        public List<Car> Cars
        {
            get { return _Cars; }
            set
            {

                if (_Cars == value)
                {
                    return;
                }   
                _Cars = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public Car _Car;
        public Car Car
        {
            get { return _Car; }
            set
            {
                if (_Car == value)
                {
                    return;
                }
                _Car = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();

            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace TreeViewTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        MainWindowViewModel _MainWindowContext = new MainWindowViewModel();

        public MainWindow()
        {


            DataContext = _MainWindowContext;
            List<String> basicFeatures = new List<string>() { "Air Conditioning", "AM/FM Radio"};
            Car Rav4 = new Car() { Make = "Toyota", Model = "Rav4", Year = 2001, Features = basicFeatures};
            Car ModelX = new Car() { Make = "Tesla", Model = "Model X", Year = 2020, Features = basicFeatures};
            List<Car> theseCars = new List<Car>() { Rav4, ModelX };
            _MainWindowContext.Car = Rav4;
            _MainWindowContext.Cars = theseCars;

            InitializeComponent();
        }


    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="TreeViewTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TreeViewTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">    
            <TreeView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Height="150">
                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding CarCollection}" DataType="{x:Type local:Cars}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Make}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeView>

        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: You never gave the item source to the control itself. You went directly to HierarchicalDataTemplate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}"
```

to the TreeView

EDIT

This is how you would lay out the cars with their respective features as child nodes.

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Height="150" ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Car}" ItemsSource="{Binding Features}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Make}"/>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

You pass the Cars to the TreeView control itself so it has a an items source.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}">
```

Then you define the template via resources. In your case it is HierarchicalDataTemplate since cars has another level.

```
<TreeView.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Car}" ItemsSource="{Binding Features}">
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

It is important to say that your HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType is Car and then you also have to define the ItemsSource. 
Basically what you are saying to WPF is: Whenever you encounter a type of Car please lay out a hierarchy and use collection of Features that you can find on the car type.

After this you define the actual content. The content is a TextBlock that shows Make property from type Car and then we define the HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemTemplate. So here we are saying to WPF, once you are laying out Car please make sure you layout the child node as well. There is no specific property to bind in your case since it is a list of strings.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Make}"/>
<HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help.  It can be hard learning complicated things like this all on your own. A little helping hand can go a really long way to putting me back on track.  Thank you